# Oreintation not change in android 2.3

Tags: android, android-layout, configuration

I have created an application, Which required to support landscape & portrait mode.

For that, I have set portrait layout in ***layout*** folder and landscape layout in ***layout-land*** folder. In android 2.3.1 simulator when i run application then first time open portrait mode i change orientation then
landscape and change layout but when again change mode then simulator change in portrait mode but layout is not change it is used landscape layout.
After all this i tried this method.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

}
```

or

`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` in manifest file. but no effects. Pls help me. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand a single word.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug with that version of the emulator and it doesn't pick up rotation changes sometimes

edit: does for me anyway >_> and works fine on phones, and I THINK i've read this somewhere before

source: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/141c1b1ba937e7a7

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13193&q=emulator%20rotate&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars
:)

Comment: Thanks for reply i checked in my device 2.2 but also in that it is not working but in simulator it is working i don't knw why is it any problem in my device.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.southparksystems.com/devzilla/2010/3/3/switching-layouts-when-screen-orientation-changes-in-android.html

Answer (score 1):

First you need to put two layouts in different folder like **layout/test_layout.xml** and **layout-land/test_layout.xml**

Then, You can create custom layout by extending **RelativeLayout** or **LinearLayout** which you used in **test_layout.xml**

Then, Inflate the test_layout.xml in custom layout class, so your problem of orienation change will be solve.